# How to pass a the image src to a function to update another image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of images that when clicked seek an HTML5 player to a given times:

```html
<img class="ib" src="/image1.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(500)">
<img class="ib" src="/image2.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(1000)">
<img class="ib" src="/image3.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(1200)">
<img class="ib" src="/image4.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(1500)">
<img class="ib" src="/image5.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(1800)">
<img class="ib" src="/image6.PNG" onclick="player.setCurrentTime(2000)">
```

What I would also like is the below source changed to the source of the image clicked:

```
<img id="large-image" src="/image1.PNG">
```

the following jQuery does part of what I need- I coded in the change to image 2, but I'd like to pick up the src of the image clicked to change the source on large-image: in the below /image2.PNG needs to be a variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ib').click(function() {
        $('#large-image').attr('src', '/image2.PNG');
    });
});
```

Comment: [Don't use the onclick attribute to trigger JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Set a data attribute on your images instead (e.g. `data-time="1000"`) and then grab the list of all images in your script and add the click event handlers there.

Comment: Within the click function, `this` refers to the clicked thing, so you can use something like $(this).attr('src') to get the src of the clicked thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, use something like `$(this).attr("src")` to grab clicked image's source then assign it to a variable then update large image's source.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ib").click(function() {
        let clickedImage = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#large-image").attr("src", clickedImage);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/55x55">
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/54x54">
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/53x53">
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/53x53">
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/51x51">
<img class="ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50">
<img id="large-image">
```